# bash find line which contains at least one element of an array

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line

I wrote a small bash script (my first one) to parse logfiles and search for lines that contains the current date and the word "ERROR", which is working so far.
Now I want to include something like a blacklist to exclude some of the lines which are found by the script. My problem is that if there is more than one element in the blacklist array the line has to contain all of the blacklist array elements to be excluded. I want to exclude the lines which contain at least one of the elements of the blacklist array not all of them.

```
...
for (( i=0; i<$arrayLength; i++ ));
    do
        serverName=$cluster-$1
        currentFile=${1}Logs[$i]
        currentFileValue="${!currentFile}"

        echo -e "\x1B[100m$serverName: $currentFileValue \x1B[0m"
        ssh root@$serverName grep ERROR $currentFileValue |
        while read line;
            do
                if [[ $line =~ .*$today.* ]] && ! [[ $line =~ ${blacklist[@]} ]]
                    then
                    echo $line
                fi
            done
    done
...
```

Thanks for your help

EDIT:

I shrank the script down to its basics for easier testing after i considered the suggestion from bfontaine. The script only uses the first element of the blacklist array.

```
#!/bin/bash

today=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)

blacklist=("Test1" "Test2")

function check_Logs () {

            grep ERROR testfile.txt |
            grep "$today" |
            grep -Ev "($blacklist)"
}

check_Logs

echo ${blacklist[@]}
```

the "testfile.txt" looks like

```
2015-11-09 ERROR Test1
2015-11-10 WARN Test1
2015-11-10 ERROR Test1
2015-11-10 ERROR Test2
2015-11-10 ERROR Test3
2015-11-10 ERROR Test4
2015-11-10 Error Test1
2015-11-11 ERROR Test1
```

Comment: Whatever collects the array should compile a regex instead.  Then grepping is a one-liner.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `grep` to filter the lines you want with a regexp and `grep -v` to filter out the lines you don’t want e.g.:

```
ssh root@$serverName grep ERROR $currentFileValue |
    grep "$today" |
    grep -Ev "($blacklist)"
```

This assumes your blacklist is in the following format: `foo|bar|qux`.

Comment: Thats very nifty, but it does not work or i dont understand the assumed blacklist format.

My blacklist array looks like: 
blacklist=("Test1" "Test2")

Only the first element of the array is getting used to exclude the lines. The second and all following elements are not being considered.